# Runtime exception of Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis, Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-coverage

I am running a project wherein `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll` is required. I have checked the path from where it is referenced and it is correct. I have checked its property as well which is like this:

[image: Properties]

yet it throws me this exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Use Help to know the tool options
```

I have tried adding it to GAC 34 and 64 bit both. But still it persists.
I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Please add [mre].

Comment: You can add this dll to your project and see if runs

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll is only applicable to the professional version

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you need to install the Visual Studio Coverage Analysis tool. You can do this by following these steps:

1. Go to the Visual Studio website: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
2. Click on the "Tools" tab.
3. Search for "coverage analysis".
4. Click on the "Download" button for the Visual Studio Coverage Analysis tool.
5. Follow the instructions on the screen to install the tool.

Once the tool is installed, you should be able to run it without any errors.
If you still get the error, try restarting your computer.

Comment: I cannot find that tool on that website, can you drop in direct link to that page?

Comment: Here's how to download it. [dotnet-coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-coverage)

Comment: this doesn't fixes that